# copy an excel formula to a new range

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet with the following data:
A1: 1
B1: `= A1 + 2`
A5: 2

I tried to create a macro to copy the formula from B1 to B5

```
Sub test()
    MsgBox Cells(1, 1)
    Cells(5, 2) = Cells(1, 2).Formula
End Sub
```

But this macro does not change the formula cell value. Meaning, the macro copies the formula `= A1 + 2` but I'd like it to be `= A5 + 2`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: copy, pastespecial formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `.Formula2R1C1` property as follows:

```
Sub copy_formula()

  Range("b5").Formula2R1C1 = Range("b1").Formula2R1C1

End Sub
```

or

```
Sub copy_formula()

  Cells(5, 2).Formula2R1C1 = Cells(1, 2).Formula2R1C1

End Sub
```